# Textarea redactor in NEXT.js

Tags: reactjs, input, next.js, textarea

I have an administration panel through which the user can edit promotions on the site . My project on NEXT.js (React).  I want to make an independent text editor, which will have paragraphs, fonts and font styles. I haven't dealt with this before, because I'm a beginner. At this stage I am trying to get the highlighted text and make it bold for example. Tell me how it is implemented:

```
const [selectText, setSelectText] = useState('')
const textRef = useRef(null);

function consolText() {
    let cursorStart = textRef.current.selectionStart;
    let cursorEnd = textRef.current.selectionEnd;
    setSelectText(textRef.current.value.substring(cursorStart, 
    cursorEnd))
}
```

Option 2

```
    const [selectText, setSelectText] = useState('')
    const [selectTextAnswer, setSelectTextAnswer] = useState('')
    const [cursorStart, setCursorStart] = useState('')
    const [cursorEnd, setCursorEnd] = useState('')
    const textRef = useRef(null);

    function consolText() {
        setCursorStart(textRef.current.selectionStart);
        setCursorEnd(textRef.current.selectionEnd);
        setSelectTextAnswer(textRef.current.value.substring(cursorStart, cursorEnd))
        console.log(selectTextAnswer)
    }
```

html

```
 <textarea ref={textRef} value={selectText}  onChange={e =>setSelectText(e.target.value)}</textarea>
    <button onClick={consolText}>selectText</button>
```

My error
I get the highlighted value, but I have to press the button twice in a row and it needs to be reset then ? and how to make the selected section for example **fdf** [image]

Or maybe someone is working with  suneditor

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are having to press the button twice, try using a normal variable instead of useState.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).